# How to know if a Composable is currently being rendered (the Composable is not inside a Lazy Composable)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I have a layout that is big enough to cause the screen to have a vertical scroll, how can I know If a certain Composable is being currently rendered (fully or partially) or not?

---

It is important to highlight that no `Lazy` Composable (like `LazyColumn`) is being used in this layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see where your Composable is on screen using Modifier.globallyPositioned{it.positionOnWindow} and comparing it with parent Composable hegiht/width or screen height/width.

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {
    var parentSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = text)
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .onSizeChanged {
                parentSize = it
            }
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(800.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    text = "parentSize: $parentSize" +
                            "positionInParent: ${it.positionInParent()}\n" +
                            "positionInRoot: ${it.positionInRoot()}\n" +
                            "positionInWindow: ${it.positionInWindow()}\n"
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]